# Installing node.js on Cpanel - CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf

Tags: node.js, cpanel

I've been trying to host my web app on bluehost via cpanel, but have ran into a bit of an issue.

I've been following these steps : https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/

However, when attempting to

```
yum install ea-ruby24-mod_passenger ea-apache24-mod_env ea-nodejs10
```

I receive this error: CRITICAL:yum.cli:Config error: Error accessing file for config file:///etc/yum.conf

I've also tried

```
yum clean all
```

```
yum install
```

and receive the same error for each.

I have already went into the WHM via root and enabled node, and the application manager, but neither node will install or will the application manager show up on my cpanel interface.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: why no one has answered this question